Can minimumElasticInstanceCount be sticky to a particular slot when using autoscaling in Azure App Service?
I'm trying to use Azure Autoscaling for my web apps in an Azure App Service running on P1V3. I'm deploying the infrastructure using a Bicep template and each app has a production and staging slot.
I can set the number of Always Ready Instances by setting the minimumElasticInstanceCount in the siteconfig section of the site in my Bicep template, and this works so let's say I have 1 prewarmed instance in the deployment slot and 2 in the prod slot.
However, when I do a slot swap, this setting moves along with the app, so I now have 2 prewarmed deployment instances and only 1 prewarmed prod instance.
Is there a way to tell Azure to keep this setting stuck to the deployment slot?

Unfortunately there is no way to "pin" this setting to a deployment slot. You could create an automation runbook that checks and fixes it on a set interval, or run a script after having done a slot swap. Hacky solutions, but there currently is no officially supported way to do this.

If you want to update the configuration setting for only deployment slot, you can use Azure CLI or PowerShell commands to update the specific slot. @Iain Brown


Is there a way to tell Azure to keep this setting stuck to the deployment slot?

There is no proper way to keep the setting stuck only to the deployment slot using bicep templates.
In Azure Portal, under environment variables of an app service, you can just enable below option (Deployment slot setting) as shown to keep the setting only to the specific deployment slot.

And also, while creating a deployment slot, you can be able to view the below option Clone settings from to clone or not to clone the app service settings and environment configurations.

Alternatively, you can use Azure CLI or PowerShell to enable the settings only to the specific slot using --slot argument as shown below.
az webapp config set
az webapp config set --resource-group "Jahnavi" --name "appslatest" --slot "slotnew" --number-of-workers 2


